# Workaround to count percents of unique values in ClickHouse

Tags: clickhouse

I have a trouble with counting percents for unique values. Theres is no problem to calculate percents with exact values (total, sum etc). But with `uniq` function result always are different which is understandable. The main problem is that percents don't add up. For example, total unique is 5000, but sum of pieces could be 4999 or 5001. For example:

```sql
WITH (
    SELECT uniq(t.id)
    FROM test.table t
) AS total

SELECT t.name as gender,
       t.age as age,
       uniq(t.id) as uniques,
       COALESCE((( uniques / total ) * 100), 0) as uniquesPercent
FROM test.table t
GROUP BY gender, age
```

So, is there any method to handle this problem. I can't use uniqExact due to performance issues. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that the same user cannot have several genders or ages (other words the same user cannot appear in more than one group) then *total* can be calculated as the sum of unique counts each group:

```sql
SELECT result.1 gender, result.2 age, result.3 uniquesPercent
FROM (
  SELECT 
    groupArray((gender, age, uniques)) groups,
    arraySum(x -> x.3, groups) total,
    arrayJoin(arrayMap(x -> (x.1, x.2, x.3 / total), groups)) result
  FROM (
    SELECT
        t.name AS gender,
        t.age AS age,
        uniq(t.id) AS uniques
    FROM test.table AS t
    GROUP BY
        gender,
        age
    )
  )
```

Comment: It gives the same percents for all groups, which is wrong. But I will try to improve this approach, thank you